# Clustering and producing final results to find next best customer to target(Ranked)

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering, predictive-modeling, unsupervised-learning

I have a problem where I need to cluster customer data that has all possible attributes to identify the next potential customer who can succeed the last customer in terms of buying a certain product. My data frame has about 5000 rows and 51 features from which I need to derive this result. I understand that first I need to perform clustering in order to form the right groups but what next? I have already done the following steps :

```
 EDA 
 Correlation analysis
 Enoding of categorical features
 Scaling of the data basis standard scalar 
 PCA - Achieved a final set of 21 components retained within 90% variance
```

First, how do I used the final components in the form of a dataset into a clustering algorithm? Second, What would be the best-suited clustering method for such a problem? Hierarchical- agglomerative?

After clustering, I need to build a model in such a manner that the final output should give me customer ID and the next best 5 customers ranked in an order basis the strongest attributes combination. For example: Spend, Gender, Salary, Area they live in, etc

This is an unsupervised problem but eventually, I need to split the dataset into a test data and train data with a target variable "Important Customers" that has a flag of 0 and 1 that defines my potential important target customers. The model should be able to give me a list of customers with their 5 potential successors in a ranked manner(highest to lowest)